# how to manually slow down asynchronous javascript requests to parse.com in order to stay below 30 requests per second?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, request, parse-platform

I'm fetching a collection called `logCollection` from `parse.com` in a node JS script on my machine. It has 200 elements. Each `log` has a link to another table (a pointer) called `start`. I need to fetch this one too.

Here is my code

```
Parse.User.logIn("user", "pass").then(function(user) {
  // Do stuff after successful login.
  console.log('succesfully logged in');
  return logCollection.fetch();
}).then(function(content) {
  console.log('done fetching logs: ' + logCollection.length);
  var promises = [];
  _.each(logCollection.models, function(thisLog) {

    promises.push(thisLog.attributes.start.fetch());

  });
  // Return a new promise that is resolved when all of the deletes are finished.
  return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
});
```

The thing is, it will fire at least 200 (`start`) fetch per second, and it will cause problems with the 30 requests per second limit at parse.com.

Is there a better way to do this? How can I slow down the way js fires the requests?

thanks

Comment: You will have to use a timer.  You can fire 30 requests.  Then use a timer to wait a second (or slightly longer), then fire 30 more requests.  Or, you can use a timer to fire one request every 30th of a second.  You will have to change the way you iterate your items (you can't use `.each()`) so that can get the next item from when a timer fires.  Usually, the way you do that is you collect all the items you want to iterate into an array (if they aren't already in an array) and you just keep track of the current iteration index in a scoped variable.

Comment: You can get the pointed-to 'start' object by using the include method on the query.  `query.include('start');`  this would eliminate all the extra queries.

Answer (score 0):

In a Parse Query, you can get the fully-fetched objects which are pointed to by that object, by using the `include` method on the query:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("SomeClass");
query.include('columnName');
query.find().then(function(results) {
  // each result will have 'columnName' as a fully fetched parse object.
});
```

This also works with sub-sub objects:

```
query.include('columnName.nestedColumnName');
```

or as an array:

```
query.include(['columnName', 'anotherPointerColumn']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came out with this solution that works very good. It was all this time on the parse documentation.

https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-series

The following code will fire one request only after the last one has been finished. Doing so, I can fire many requests without worrying about getting to the limit.

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Comments");
query.equalTo("post", 123);

query.find().then(function(results) {
  // Create a trivial resolved promise as a base case.
  var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
  _.each(results, function(result) {
    // For each item, extend the promise with a function to delete it.
    promise = promise.then(function() {
      // Return a promise that will be resolved when the delete is finished.
      return result.destroy();
    });
  });
  return promise;

}).then(function() {
  // Every comment was deleted.
});
```